# Does a connection to an Excel file deteriorates the performance of my script?

Tags: excel, performance, optimization, cplex, opl

I'm a engineering student, new user at CPLEX. I'm currently trying to improve the performance of my model.

The input for my model (using CPLEX and OPL) is entered through a connection to an Excel file.

1) Does this connection deteriorates the performance of my model? Should I entered the parameters directly on the .dat?

2) Does the size of the Excel file also influences the script performance? I have multiple information in that excel. Should I reduce it to the information needed only?

Comment: An answer below [recommends the profiler](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039021&aid=1) to check where the bottleneck is.

Answer (score 0):

See OPL profiler

In CPLEX documentation you may have a look at IDE and OPL > CPLEX Studio IDE > IDE Tutorials > Profiling the execution of a model > Identifying slow and memory-consuming model elements

> Description of the profiling information
>
> Describes the information about execution time, memory consumption and
>   model extraction, collected after execution of the model.
>
> When execution stops, the information collected about execution time,
>   memory consumption, and model extraction is organized in tabular form
>   in the Profiler tab.
>
> Note: 
>   1.If the profiler table is empty and the run configuration includes a settings file, first make sure the “Collect profiling information”
>   option is turned on in the Language/General window of the settings
>   editor.
>
> 2.The profiler measures "system time" and not “wall-clock time”. See Processing time vs. user time
>
> 3.The figures shown in the illustrations may be different on your machine.
>
> Each column header is a sort criterion (see Sorting) and there are two
>   icons at the top right of the Profiler tab for the commands Copy
>   contents to clipboard and Customize thresholds. The Description column
>   presents the execution steps in sequential order as a tree. The root
>   item corresponds to the full execution.

[image]

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039021&aid=1

To check where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Using profiler, 40% of my time is for "LOAD_MODEL Configuration1", being 38% for "LOAD_DATA C:\Users(etc)". If I entered my inputs directly on the .dat file instead of loading them from an Excel file, would my efficiency improve?

Comment: What you can try, if your data is already in the excel file, is to use printExternalData https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/refjsopl/html/IloOplModel.html#printExternalData to write the excel content in a .dat file and then you ll use that file. You may also export that .dat in the IDE

Comment: I'll try that! Thank you so much for your help